# Как использовать SYMBOL (иконку) из SVG спрайта в CSS на локалке?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-спрайт

Я использую svg спрайты с помощью `<symbol>`. 
Мне нужно использовать иконки у CSS. Нужно использовать так: `background: url('../images/symbols.svg#header-pattern')`
она не отображается поскольку на локалке чтобы видеть остальные иконки нужно инлайново подключать *svg, дать ему `display:none`*, а потом только использовать `<use xlink:href="#logo"></use>`.

Даже при том, что у меня инлайново файл подключен на странице, но я всё равно не могу использовать иконки спрайта в CSS.

Comment: а ты use между какими тегами расположил ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский да, конечно. но суть вопроса не у отображении в HTML, а в CSS :)